# iPhone SDK - possible to have multiple splash screens?

Tags: ios

I'm making an app with a different screen for its first run. Once it has completed its first run, this screen is never shown again. The issue I have is that my launch image is built to look like the view that the user sees every other time they run the app, so at first run the loading screen looks weird. Is there any way to have one loading screen for first run and one loading screen for other runs? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple or dynamic launch images. Even with the new storyboard/nib launch files, they are still quite static.

Make sure to open an enhancement report with Apple, requesting this feature.

In the meantime, consider a slight change of your flow to first display the initial view, and have an animation to display your first-launch view. This way, the transition will be smoother and more natural to your users.